# Ubuntu 10.04 broken package (build-essential)

Tags: 10.04, package-management

I do know there are questions like mine, but I couldn't get it work reading their answers. I'm trying to install build-essential, but the package is broken, therefore I can't install the needed compiler.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:   build-essential:
Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or libc-dev
Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.3.1) but it is not going to be installed E: Broken packages
```

What I tried so far:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential -f
```

None of the above worked. I suppose the problem is in my sources.list, here it is:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Anyway, if someone needs the answer, the problem was in my sources.list. I just changed it then

> sudo apt-get update

and the package was downloaded and installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install gcc

sudo apt-get install g++

sudo apt-get install libc6-dev

sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  g++: Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: g++-4.4 (>= 4.4.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-4.4 (>= 4.4.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

Comment: Updated the answer with command to install gcc

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  gcc: Depends: gcc-4.4 (>= 4.4.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                   libc-dev
E: Broken packages

Comment: Did you try to install gcc?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to install gcc.

Comment: What was the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use aptitude instead of apt-get.
In my case it gave me a solution to fix dependencies automatically.